# Embedded SWF in Facebook with MochiAds Loader, access FB flashvars?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a flash game embedded on Facebook but need access to the flashvars facebook passes to all embedded games. However I am using the mochiads preloader meaning that _root.fb_sig_user is always undefined?

How do I get to the variables?

```
stage.loaderInfo.parameters.fb_sig_user
```

Was my best guess and it doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: I guess `stage.getChildAt(0).root.loaderInfo.parameters.fb_sig_user;` would work on AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
paramList = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

trace(paramList["fb_sig_user"];

fb_session = new FacebookSessionUtil("api_key","api_secret", stage.loaderInfo);
```